# Derive the distribution of the range of a sample of size $2$ from a distribution having density function $f(x)=2x$,$0<x<1.$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, solution-verification, density-function

This problem statement has been featured in a different question, but the user who posted that question was asking about clarification of the definitions within the problem statement, while I am trying to verify my solution, so I don't believe this should be considered as a repost. One important nuance here is that we're supposed to solve this problem without having been 'taught' anything about order statistics and sample sizes, just treating it as a problem like any other joint distribution problems that we have been doing (i.e. just figuring out the region of integration, and solving the integrals.)

My attempt:

Define $R = |X_2 - X_1|$.

For $r\in(0,1)$, $P(R<r) = P(|X_2 - X_1| < r) = 2P(X_2 - X_1 < r)$ by symmetry.

Computing $P(X_2 - X_1 < r):$

$\displaystyle{P(X_2 - X_1 < r) = \iint_{x_2-x_1<r}f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)dx_1dx_2 = \int_0^{r}\int_{0}^{r+x_1}(2x_1)(2x_2)dx_2dx_1}$.

I am a little unconfident that I chose the correct limits of integration, and that I set up everything else correctly so far. But if I did, then computing this integral yields $\frac{17}6r^4, r\in(0,1)$. Thus, (and apologies for my poor MathJax):

$F_R(r) = 1$ when $r\geq1$,

$F_R(r) = \dfrac{17}3r^4$ when $r\in(0,1)$,

$F_R(r) = 0$ when $r\leq0$.

Differentiation yields that:

$f_R(r) = \dfrac{68}3r^3$ when $r\in(0,1)$,

$f_R(r) = 0$ when $r\notin(0,1)$.

Everything check out?

Comment: $F_R(r) = \dfrac{17}3r^4$ looks implausible for a CDF, for example when $r=0.999$

Comment: @Henry Agreed, and my 'density' doesn't integrate to 1 when the integral is evaluated over all reals. I'm not really sure why my approach didn't work though.

Comment: After you have used the symmetry argument, you are only considering the region $X_2 \geq X_1$. So the lower limit will have to be $x_1$. Also the upper limit would be $\min\{x_1 + r, 1\}$ since $X_2 \leq 1$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Why is the region we are considering not $X_2 \geq X_1 + r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are interested in the probability mass in the region $R = \{(x_1,x_2): |x_1 - x_2| \leq r, x_1 \in [0,1], |x_2| \in [0,1] \}$. This is essentially the region in the unit square between the lines $x_2 = x_1 - r$ and $x_2 = x_1 + r$. To simplify our calculation, we will calculate the region in the unit square outside $R$. Since, by symmetry the mass of the region below the line $x_2 = x_1 - r$ is the same as that of above the line $x_2 = x_1 + r$ (as you have already noted), we will only compute the former. Denoting it by $p$, we have,
\begin{align*}
p & = \int_{r}^1 \int_{0}^{x_1 - r} (2x_1) \cdot (2x_2) \ \mathrm{d}x_2 \ \mathrm{d}x_1 \\
& =  \int_{r}^1 2x_1(x_1 - r)^2 \ \mathrm{d}x_1 \\
& =  2\int_{r}^1 [r(x_1 - r)^2 + (x_1 - r)^3] \ \mathrm{d}x_1 \\
& =  \frac{2r(1 - r)^3}{3} + \frac{(1 - r)^4}{2}.
\end{align*}

Thus, the required probability is $1 - 2p$.